# DNN website: [SQL] Access Is Denied for Non-DNN-Framework Data Access

Tags: sql, dotnetnuke, access-denied

In a DNN page containing ANYTHING that accesses custom data (i.e., site-specific tables), we always get the following error:

Access Is Denied

[Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied] [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. 
    Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
     (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)]
     System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +6749670 System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +815

Current config:

IIS pool set up as a local service
 SQL runs as a localsystem service

All of the users have the proper DB ownership

DB can be accessed OK for the main DNN install (i.e. users can log in and all DNN-related database infrastructure can be read and displayed from the database), but for the custom modules that read the Connection string from the web.config, it throws the error above.

We've tried to:

Change to poolidentity and give the permission to that particular user/service, and we are experiencing the same problem.

---

I'm not sure if IIS Application Pools or SQL users are the issue. The error seems to be about the SQL instance which may or may not be set up correctly. However, if it's an SQL instance issue, as per the error message, we are not sure why database access for DNN functions (login, tabs, modules, etc.) are allowed but other connections (via LINQ data context for site-specific schema, or via  where we hard-code the connection string) are denied.

Comment: Do you have two different Databases? One for DNN and one for the modules?

Comment: One Database. I think the DNN Install only creates 1 database, at least that's we have.

Comment: EDIT: One Database. All our modules (even custom modules) access the database that came installed with the DNN setup.

Comment: Are the tables under a different schema, other than DBO?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44649/discussion-between-mickael-caruso-and-chris-hammond)